# Can't Share AJAX HTML, because Parent Page Meta Being Read

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a parent page with thumbnails that link to a Jquery AJAX modal, so that when someone closes the AJAX html, the user will return to the scrolled part of the parent page that they clicked on. Everything is working as far as navigation and related thumbs etc. The only problem I am running into is that when i try to share the AJAX html page, the parent  is being read, and not the AJAX html page meta.

Is it possible to use some script to have the first set of meta elements skipped and the AJAX meta read? Does that make sense?

Here is the page I'm working on --> [Example](https://santafe.com/videos/)

HTML:

```
 <a class="thumb {url_title}" rel="modal:open" href="/{segment_1}/{url_title}">Blah</a>
```

SHARE BUTTONS:

```
 <!-- AddToAny BEGIN -->
      <a class="a2a_dd" href="https://www.addtoany.com/share"><i class="far fa-share-alt"></i></a>
      <script>
       var a2a_config = a2a_config || {};
       a2a_config.onclick = 1;
       a2a_config.num_services = 6;
      </script>
      <script async src="https://static.addtoany.com/menu/page.js"></script>
<!-- AddToAny END -->
```

Jquery:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"> . </script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.css" />
```

[image]

Comment: Teemu, I am using jquery ajax, so its just modal="open" command. I added a little more to illustrate what Im talking about. Thx

Comment: I yet don't quite get the system. This "_AJAX page_", what exactly is it? Are you trying to create a document within a document?

Comment: Yes, did you click on the example link? You'll get the direction Im going if you go there...

Comment: What if I set up a conditional, if the a.thumb is clicked, turn off the first set of meta tags? Do you think that would work?

Comment: Umh .. unless I haven't totally missed something (new?), you can't create a document within another document, without an embedding element ex. iframe or object. Could you show the snippet where you actually create this new "document"? I.e. the `done` part of the AJAX call. What comes to "_meta part_", I assume that is inside `head`, which is parsed when the page is loaded, and is guaranteed to be totally parsed and scripts in it executed before starting to parse the body of the page. Changes to meta elements are ignored once the head has been parsed.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for illustrating that. Im figuring that it might not work.

Comment: This question is not clear and you're using a lot of phrases that do not make sense. When you use AJAX, it's a method to send/receive data via HTTP. It alone does not have HTML Pages or elements. None of your code makes any real sense and seems very disconnected. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example